# C# Transactionscope - insert/select in same transaction, multiple connections

Tags: c#, transactionscope, msdtc

I want to have a parent object delete itself and it's child object in a single transactionscope.  I also want to check in both cases if the object to delete exists, and if the user has rights to the object.  Consider the following code:

I get the MSDTC on server is unavailable exception.  Is there anyway to pass the connection through my service methods?

Please see the example below:

// classes Flight, FlightService, FlightDao
// classes Pilot, PilotService, PilotDao

```
// FlightService
public void deleteFlight(Flight flight) {
    FlightDao flightDao = new FlightDao();
    Flight existingFlight = flightDao.findById(flight.Id);
    if (existingFlight != null) {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
            try {
                PilotService.Instance.deletePilot(flight.Pilot);
                flightDao.delete(flight);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.Error(e.Message, e);
                throw new ServiceException(e.Message, e);
            }
            scope.Complete();   
        }
    }       
}

// PilotService
public void deleteFlight(Pilot pilot) {
    PilotDao pilotDao = new PilotDao();
    Pilot existingPilot = pilotDao.findById(pilot.Id); // THIS LINE RIGHT HERE THROWS EXCEPTION
    if (existingPilot != null) { 
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
            try {               
                pilotDao.delete(pilot);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.Error(e.Message, e);
                throw new ServiceException(e.Message, e);
            }
            scope.Complete();   
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of the DAO where the exception is being thrown?

Comment: I'm curious as to why this is attempting to escalate to a DTC transaction.  Are pilots and flights on different databases, or using different connection strings?  The quick fix is to enable DTC on your web server, but DTC transactions are very expensive and it would be better to use a native SQL transaction.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the prompt replies guys! I will edit the original post with the DAO implementation and the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that I was trying to use the same SqlDataReader multiple times within the same loop.  This defintiely does not work inside a transaction.

Example:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(...);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.read()) {
  return buildMyObject(reader);
}

private MyObject buildMyObject(SqlDataReader reader) {
  MyObject o1 = new MyObject();
  // set fields on my object from reader

  // broken! i was attempting create a new sql connection here and attempt to use a reader
  // but the reader is already in use.
  return o1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using multiple data context layers with transactions. You need to pass one to another.
 "**deletePilot**" call should execute within same data context. One solutions is to have constructors at your data access layer to accept data context from another data service. They will be performing operations at same context.

```
public void deleteFlight(IYourDataContext context, Pilot pilot) {
PilotDao pilotDao = new PilotDao(context);
//do operations now in same context.
...
```